# How to make a common class for common code in a controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have two controllers both are derivated from a base controller. The code inside them is exactly the same. The only difference is in constructors. Below is my code:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/v2")]
    public class CategoryController : BaseController
    {
        private IGetTroubleTicketService getTroubleTicketService;
        private ICategoryService categoryService;
        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor for initialization
        /// </summary>
        public CategoryController()
        {
            getTroubleTicketService = MethodFactory.Create<IGetTroubleTicketService>();
            getTroubleTicketService.SetProvider(new ServiceProvider(Global.Container));
            categoryService = MethodFactory.Create<ICategoryService>();
            categoryService.SetProvider(new ServiceProvider(Global.Container));
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Retrieve all Categories
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Categories(Id, Label)</returns>
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("categoryRef")]
        public HttpResponseMessage Categories()
        {            
            try
            {
                // Validate User Id and Application Id
                var user = ValidateUserAndApplication(getTroubleTicketService);
                var userLanaguage = Convert.ToInt32(user.Language, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                var categories = categoryService.CategoriesData(userLanaguage);              
                LoggingRequest("categoryRef",null);
                response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, categories);               
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                //CheckError
                CheckError(exception);
            }
            return response;
        }

}
```

The second one is

```
[RoutePrefix("api/v2")]
    public class ProblemCategoryController : BaseController
    {
        private IGetTroubleTicketService getTroubleTicketService;
        private ICategoryService categoryService;
        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor for initialization
        /// </summary>
        public ProblemCategoryController()
        {
            getTroubleTicketService = MethodFactory.Create<IGetTroubleTicketService>();
            getTroubleTicketService.SetProvider(new ServiceProvider(Global.Container));
            categoryService = MethodFactory.Create<ICategoryService>();
            categoryService.SetProvider(new ServiceProvider(Global.Container));
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Retrieve all Natures of problem
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Categories(Id, Label)</returns>
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("problemCategoryRef")]
        public HttpResponseMessage ProblemCategories()
        {
            try
            {
                // Validate User Id and Application Id
                var user = ValidateUserAndApplication(getTroubleTicketService);
                var userLanaguage = Convert.ToInt32(user.Language, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                var categories = categoryService.CategoriesData(userLanaguage);

                LoggingRequest("problemCategoryRef", null);

                response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, categories);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                //CheckError
                CheckError(exception);
            }
            return response;

        }
```

Now as you can see the internal code is exactly the same which I want to avoid creating a Helper class. How can I make this common class for it so as to remove code duplicacy? It's possible without rewrite all the context code to get User and Id app?

Comment: If the code is exactly the same, why don't you just make a one controller and use it for both instead of calling two separate ones? The constructors appear the same btw.

Comment: Why not make a single controller and whatever parameter makes difference (if there is any) then use that parameter to create the desired class/ object or invoke function. By d way i can see both have different routes,as James already mentioned your constructor is also same, why not use query parameter to differ the logic creation.

Comment: Because is an architecture requirement, same list of category is called from differents parts of application. This don't change much more, i'm agree with you there is not contraint but it's like this.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this

```
public class NatureOfProblemHelper : BaseController
    {
        private IGetTroubleTicketService getTroubleTicketService;
        private ICategoryService categoryService;
        private string resourceName;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="NatureOfProblemHelper"/> class.
        /// Constructor for initialization.
        /// <param name="resource">Resource requested by user.</param>
        /// </summary>
        public NatureOfProblemHelper(string resource)
        {
            getTroubleTicketService = MethodFactory.Create<IGetTroubleTicketService>();
            getTroubleTicketService.SetProvider(new ServiceProvider(Global.Container));
            categoryService = MethodFactory.Create<ICategoryService>();
            categoryService.SetProvider(new ServiceProvider(Global.Container));
            resourceName = resource;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Retrieve all Natures of problem.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Categories(Id, Label).</returns>
        public HttpResponseMessage GetNaturesOfProblem()
        {
            // Validate User Id and Application Id
            var user = ValidateUserAndApplication(getTroubleTicketService);
            var userLanaguage = Convert.ToInt32(user.Language, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            var categories = categoryService.CategoriesData(userLanaguage);
            LoggingRequest(resourceName, null);
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, categories);
        }
```

And then into each controller

```
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("problemCategoryRef")]
        public HttpResponseMessage ProblemCategories()
        {
            try
            {
                response = natureOfProblem.NaturesOfProblem();
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                //CheckError
                CheckError(exception);
            }
            return response;
        }
```

This build, but I can't get the context that comes from this variable

```
// Validate User Id and Application Id
var user = ValidateUserAndApplication(getTroubleTicketService);
```

Why if I put the same lines of code directly in my controller works but if I put in my Helper it doesn't work??